# Open pdf from resource folder in Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-mobile

In Titanium i want to open pdf file which is stored in resources folder , onclick event it should get opened on adobe or any client which is already installed on my mobile device

Comment: Which platform you are going for ?   Thanks

Comment: You can use webview in titanium to open a pdf file.

Comment: both android and iphone i have stored pdf file on resource folder can you please tell how to open it on webview

Answer (score 2):

you can use intent to open pdf for android and for iphone you can use webview.

```
var strFileName = 'test.pdf';
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, strFileName);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action : Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
    type : 'application/pdf',
    data : f.getNativePath()
}));
```

Comment: or you can visit below link for reference.
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/72361/open-pdf-file-on-android